# Android get distance X and Y beetween Locations

Tags: android

I know `location1.distanceTo(location2)`

I need to calculate

```
distanceX
```

and

```
distanceY
```

from two locations. Is there a way to do it?

**CORRECT ANSWER based on njzk2 answer**

```
private Point getDistanceXY(Location location1, Location location2) {

    int angle = (int) location1.bearingTo(location2);

    Location interm  = new Location(location1);
    interm.setLongitude(location2.getLongitude());

    int distanceX = (int) location1.distanceTo(interm);
    int distanceY = (int) location2.distanceTo(interm);

    if (angle<=-90) distanceX=-distanceX;
    else if (angle>-90 && angle<0) {
        distanceX=-distanceX;
        distanceY=-distanceY;
    }

    Log.e("distXY "+name, distanceX+"  "+distanceY+" "+angle);

    return new Point(distanceX, distanceY);
}
```

Comment: what are they? if your distance is your hyphotenus, location1.distanceTo(location2) it is not enough, you need to find their angles too

Comment: Please define that do mean as distanceX and distanceY. At least, in which units they are measured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is create a middle point :

```
Location interm = new Location(location1);
iterm.setLongitude(location2.getLongitude());
```

And then,

```
double distanceX = location1.distance(interm);
double distanceY = interm.distance(location2);
```

Comment: note, however, that measuring the distanceY first leads to a different solution, because of the projection (this is more obvious close to the poles)

Comment: It is not working... I d like to show my map GPS POI's in a 2D surface (it is an ImageView, where I just Override the onDraw) BTW, I have a starter POI, and I like to draw all the POI's in the 2D world from the startPOI

Comment: this is only returning positive numbers, so this is my probleme...I have to figure it out what is the direction

Comment: you could use location.bearingTo to get the angle.

Comment: (still don't understand why you need X and Y distance, not just overall)

Comment: Because I have a starter POI (lets say 47.1234, 17.1234, this in 2D will be x=100px, y=100px)...the next POI lets say (47.0012, 17.1111) ->>> how to find out where is that POI in the 2D canvas map?  I have to calculate the distanceX, and distanceY, it is working, WHEN the starterPOI is the left/top POI on my map, but when a POI is top of my starter POI, the distY will be positive too, but it will be negative number

Comment: 2D projection of sphere coordinates is slightly more tricky than this

Comment: There are many. I would probably extrapolate based on the coordinates of the corners of the displayed map, but that depends on the particular situation. I assume you are not using google maps api ?

Comment: No I can't use Google Maps, and OSM too. I have to draw this POIs to an imageview/canvas with a custom map. There will be only one starter POI (LEFT/TOP corner of the map)

Comment: ok. depending on how big is your map and how close to the poles you are, (a city or a small country under the 60° should be ok), you can consider a semi-linear projection. you can interpolate linearly in the Y, and linearly interpolate the correction for the linear interpolation on the X (if that's clear?) if you are looking at a world map, though, it won't work

Comment: the map is 4-5 km2 at the moment, and here is in Austria

Answer (score 1):

You can use [bearingTo()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#bearingTo%28android.location.Location%29) in combination with [distanceTo()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceTo%28android.location.Location%29) and a little bit of trigonometry to calculate the X and Y components.

```
double distY = distance * sin(angle);
double distX = distance * cos(angle);
```

Comment: Sadly this not working, incorrect places will be on my canvas

Comment: Are you sure that the trig functions you are using are using radians or degrees properly? What other debugging have you done to figure out what is wrong?